# Setup ASP.Net Core Authorize and Authentication Properly in a .Net Core 3.0 project

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-core, .net-core-3.0

I currently work on a .net core api project with VSCode, and I want to integrate ASP.NET Core Authentication and Authorization with a cookie.

I tried to add `services.AddAuthentication();` and `services.AddAuthorization();` in `Startup.cs`. I've also add the `[Authorize]` attribute in my `UsersController.cs`.

```cs
[Authorize]
    [Route("api/Users")]
    [ApiController]
    public class UsersController : ControllerBase
```

The problem it's that when I launch my app, even if I don't created user or roles, I still can have access to my API. (`https://localhost:5001/api/Users`)

I tried to setup my `launchSettings.json` like the following:

```
  "iisSettings": {
    "windowsAuthentication": false,
    "anonymousAuthentication": false,
    "iisExpress": {
      "applicationUrl": "http://localhost:49086",
      "sslPort": 44343
    }
```

But I still have access to my API. How deny the access, if there are no user or roles?

I surely missed something but I don't know what.

Thank you in advance for your help!

Comment: Maybe change "windowsAuthentication": to true instead of false ?

Comment: I tried it but I still have acces to my API User

Comment: I don't see how did you implement authentication and authorization. AutrhorizeAttribute will allow access to any authorized user, so maybe your configuration tells that all are authorized - but we don't see your implementation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well I'm kinda dumb, I found this solution from a related problem with ASP Mvc 5, I added to my `Startup.cs` the followed line in my `ConfigurationServices`:

```cs
services.AddMvcCore(option => option.EnableEndpointRouting = false).AddAuthorization();
```

And in `Configure`:

```cs
app.UseMvc();
```

And now `[Authorize]` in my Controllers works, if I'm not authenticated I can't have access to my APIs.